# in Pokémon alpha sapphire when do you get latias

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

How far in the game do I get latias...
What gym and route do I get it after
I did research but I disnt find
What I was looking for...

I don't have the game yet so I don't want major spoilers that will spoil the whole game

Answer (score 1):

You will have the opportunity to get Latias in Alpha Sapphire after Wattson's gym in Mauville City.

E: On Route 118.